# How do I adjust my display for 1080p?

Tags: display

Just a quick question...

I got a new 24" hd tv to use as a pc monitor and have windows pre installed.

In the windows 7 display settings {control panel/Display} is a option to make things on the screen appear bigger this works great at high res and I was wondering if any one knew a similar setting or program to get the same effect on Ubuntu.

Don't mind if its for Unity, gnome or KDE etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

in unity

1. under system preferences (click right top on the wheel)
2. choose universal access
3. in the first tab you can alter the text size

I am not sure if everything is correctly named because i use the dutch translation
but normaly you should get there

Comment: The same goes for any desktop environment, up the res then increase the font size.

Comment: Cheers I will try this sounds about right..